# Cutting out the interior of a 2-cell to prove a space deformation retracts.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $D$ be a 2-disc with $k$ open discs removed. Compute the homology of the pair $(D, ∂D)$.

The homology groups of $D$ and $\partial D$ are pretty straight forward. Then one can use the long exact sequence. A full possible solution is here: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626471/homology-groups-of-the-pair-d-partial-d-where-d-is-a-2-disc-with-k-ope)

I just have one question: We need to calculate the maps $i^{1}_{*}$ induced from the inclusion. Now the best way to "see" what this map does, is to notice that our space deformation retracts onto the wedge sum of $k$-circles. This is clear if you draw the picture. 
But is there a way to proof this is indeed a deformation retraction in a formally satisfying way?

Essentially i just want to "cut out" the interior of the 2-cell and this seems to be far more problematic then anticipated.

The theorems i have at my disposal are essentially everything Hatcher.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What precisely is $i^1$?

Comment: In the long exact sequence of the pair $(D,\partial D)$ the map $i^{1}_{*}:H_1(\partial D) \rightarrow H_1(D)$ is the map induced by the inclusion map.

Comment: For the record, I do not believe you need to understand the homotopy type of $D$ in this manner to carry out that long exact sequence calculation, but I got carried anyway explaining how to understand $D$, so that's that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103170/the-plane-minus-n-points-deformation-retracts-onto/4103312#4103312

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall answer how to determine the homotopy type of this space. This is geometrically intuitive, but not so easy to formalize (and there's a lot of "routine" details involved) and that translation of intuition to formal argument is often skipped over. For simplicities sake, I'll only argue that $D$ is homotopy-equivalent to a wedge sum of $k$ circles.

First of all, a disk without its center deformation retracts onto its boundary, and doing this for all $k$ disjoint disks simultaneously yields a deformation retraction of the disk $D^2$ with $k$ interior points removed to your space $D$. Thus, we can and shall only consider the space $X=D^2-\{x_1,\dotsc,x_k\}$ for some $x_1,\dotsc,x_k\in\mathrm{int}(D^2)$ instead. Here's two ways of proceeding:

*Differential Topology:* If you know a little bit of differential topology, you can appeal to the fact that if $M$ is a smooth manifold (with boundary) of dimension $\ge2$, the diffeomorphism group $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ acts $k$-transitively on $\mathrm{int}(M)$ for any $k\ge1$. This allows us to replace the arbitrary choice of points $x_1,\dotsc,x_k$ with an explicit choice, e.g. $k$ points that are equally spaced on the circle of radius $1/2$. Then, we may explicitly draw the wedge sum of $k$ circles in the plane as a "flower" $F$ with one "petal" $P_i$ for each $x_i$, $i=1,\dotsc,k$. E.g. for $k=3$ you get something like [image: 1]

Let me remark that drawing a picture is perfectly rigorous here as we have chosen *explicit* points. You can come up with nice formulae for such images, but this is not necessary. (Perhaps you wanna object that I've just drawn the image for $k=3$, but we need to consider all $k$. One way to do it in general is take a sufficiently thin petal and rotate it around $k$ times. The precise shape of the petal does not matter; only that it satisfies some basic properties.)

Now, $X$ deformation retracts onto $F$ in two steps. Note that the complement of $F$ in $X$ has $k+1$ components: The component having boundary $P_i$ is called the interior of the petal $P_i$ and the last one is called the exterior. First, the union of $P_i$ and its interior deformation retracts to $P_i$. If $z$ is a point of this union, the straight ray through $z$ emanating from $x_i$ meets $P_i$ in exactly one point. The deformation retraction is the straight-line homotopy taking each $z$ to that respective point. Having done this for each petal, we obtain that $X$ deformation retracts onto the union of the flower $F$ and its exterior. Now, for each point $z$ in this union, the stray ray emanating from $z$ to the origin meets the flower in some first point (which may or may not be the origin) and we obtain the desired deformation retraction onto $F$ by the straight-line homotopy taking each $z$ to that respective point.

*Homotopy Theory:* This method does not presume any additional facts. We proceed inductively. The case $k=1$ is proven by observing that a disk with an interior point removed deformation retracts to the boundary (this is another argument by straight-line homotopy). For the induction step, suppose $k\ge2$ and the previous cases are proven. You can find a straight line $L$ that does not meet any of the points $x_1,\dotsc,x_k$ and separates $D^2$ into two hemi-disks $D_1$ and $D_2$ with $x_1\in\mathrm{int}(D_1)$ and $x_2\in\mathrm{int}(D_2)$ (this requires a little argument). The line $L$ is contractible and $(X,L)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property (this requires another little argument), so the quotient map $X\rightarrow X/L$ is a homotopy-equivalence. The space $X$ is the union of $X_1=X\cap D_1$ and $X_2=X\cap D_2$ along $L$, so $X/L$ is the wedge sum of $X_1/L$ and $X_2/L$.

Now, $X_1$ is the hemi-disk $D_1$ with some $k_1$ points and $X_2$ is the hemi-disk $D_2$ with some $k_2$ points removed. In total, $k_1+k_2=k$ and we know that $k_1,k_2<k$, because at least one point has been removed from either hemi-disk by construction. For $i=1,2$, there is a homeomorphism between the hemi-disk $D_i$ and the disk $D^2$ that takes $L$ to some arc $A$ on the boundary $\partial D^2=S^1$ and a homeomorphism between $D^2/A$ and $D^2$ (yet another little argument; this is perhaps not quite obvious) and these all take the boundaries into another, so they yield homeomorphisms between $X_i/L$ and a disk with some $k_i$ points removed, which is homotopy-equivalent to a wedge sum of $k_i$ circles by induction hypothesis. In total, $X=X_1/L\vee X_2/L$ is homotopy-equivalent to a wedge sum of $k_1+k_2=k$ circles. Thus, the induction goes through... Except I've subtly lied to you, because "the wedge sum" depends on base-points, which the argument has no control over, so it remains to argue the technicality that if you take $k$ circles and wedge $k$ times, the homotopy type of the resulting space does not depend on where you wedge them or in which constellation. This is the case since all spaces involved are path-connected and have the homotopy extension property with respect to any basepoint.

Comment: This was a perfect explanation, Thanks alot!